# Solo me muestra la ultima parte de mi Arraylist en el TextView

Tags: json, arraylist, post, textview

tengo un problema, quiero mostrar el "rowset" del siguiente JSON:

```
{
"MQ0302A_DATAREQ": {
    "tableId": "VMQ03421",
    "rowset": [
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 26,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 24085,
            "ORDEN": 622682,
            "TIPO": "SO",
            "CLIENTE": "ROSA, JUAN RICARDO",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "17/11/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 34,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 24085,
            "ORDEN": 622634,
            "TIPO": "SO",
            "CLIENTE": "ROSA, JUAN RICARDO",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "29/10/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 11313,
            "ORDEN": 622626,
            "TIPO": "SM",
            "CLIENTE": "COSUFI S.A.",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "28/10/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 11313,
            "ORDEN": 622625,
            "TIPO": "SM",
            "CLIENTE": "COSUFI S.A.",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "28/10/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 11313,
            "ORDEN": 622628,
            "TIPO": "SM",
            "CLIENTE": "COSUFI S.A.",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "28/10/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 11313,
            "ORDEN": 622623,
            "TIPO": "SM",
            "CLIENTE": "COSUFI S.A.",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "28/10/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 11313,
            "ORDEN": 622624,
            "TIPO": "SM",
            "CLIENTE": "COSUFI S.A.",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "28/10/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 24085,
            "ORDEN": 622718,
            "TIPO": "SO",
            "CLIENTE": "ROSA, JUAN RICARDO",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "29/11/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 24085,
            "ORDEN": 622630,
            "TIPO": "SO",
            "CLIENTE": "ROSA, JUAN RICARDO",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "28/10/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 24085,
            "ORDEN": 622683,
            "TIPO": "SO",
            "CLIENTE": "ROSA, JUAN RICARDO",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "19/11/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 11313,
            "ORDEN": 622629,
            "TIPO": "SM",
            "CLIENTE": "COSUFI S.A.",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "28/10/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 11313,
            "ORDEN": 622627,
            "TIPO": "SM",
            "CLIENTE": "COSUFI S.A.",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "28/10/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 2,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 15187,
            "ORDEN": 622578,
            "TIPO": "SO",
            "CLIENTE": "T.A.E.S.A. AGRIC. GANADERA",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "18/10/2021"
        }
    ],
    "records": 13,
    "moreRecords": false
},
"jde__status": "SUCCESS",
"jde__startTimestamp": "2022-03-21T11:56:42.939-0300",
"jde__endTimestamp": "2022-03-21T11:56:44.956-0300",
"jde__serverExecutionSeconds": 2.017
```

}

pero solo me aparece

```
    {
            "CANTIDAD": 2,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 15187,
            "ORDEN": 622578,
            "TIPO": "SO",
            "CLIENTE": "T.A.E.S.A. AGRIC. GANADERA",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "18/10/2021"
        }
```

Les muestro como me aparece en el Android Emulador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedo darme cuenta por mi "Toast.makeText" que llega a leer todo pero no lo aplica en el textView, aunque me gustaria plasmarlo en una grilla a todo el JSON.

Acá va mi código:

Main Activity

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //list = findViewById(R.id.list);
    user = findViewById(R.id.Usuario);
    contraseña = findViewById(R.id.Password);
    informeConexion = findViewById(R.id.conexionActivity);
    prueba = findViewById(R.id.prueba);
    prueba3 = findViewById(R.id.prueba3);
    prueba4= findViewById(R.id.prueba4);

    public void Prueba(View v){

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(" http://137.116.116.34:91/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    Conexion conexion = retrofit.create(Conexion.class);

    Cuerpo login3 = new Cuerpo("xxx", "xxxx", "xxx");
    Call<LoginUser> call2 = conexion.getUser(login3);
    call2.enqueue(new Callback<LoginUser>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginUser> call, Response<LoginUser> response) {
            int statusCode = response.code();

            if(statusCode == 200) {
                informeConexion.setText("code: " + response.code() + " Conexión exitosa " + "\n");


                Mq0302aDatareq contactList =  response.body().getMq0302a();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OUTPUT : "+response.body(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("MainActivity", "posts loaded from API");
                //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OUTPUT : "+response.body().getContacts(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                    Log.d("MainActivity", "posts loaded from API");                 List<Contact> contactList =  response.body().getContacts();                    for(int i = 0; i<contactList.size(); i++)
                for(int i = 0; i<contactList.getRowset().size(); i++) {
                    String tableId = contactList.getTableId(i);
                    int moreRecords = contactList.getRecords(i);
                    boolean records = contactList.getMoreRecords(i);


                    ArrayList<Rowset> rowset = (ArrayList<Rowset>) contactList.getRowset();
                    String cliente = rowset.get(i).getCliente();
                    int home = rowset.get(i).getCantidad();
                    int office = rowset.get(i).getOrden();

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OUTPUT : "+statusCode +", "+ tableId +", "+ moreRecords +", "+ records +",¨ " + cliente +"," + home +","+ office , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    prueba.setText("Cliente: " + cliente  + "\n" + "Cantidad: " + home + "\n" +"Orden: " + office + "\n"+ response.body() + "\n");
                    prueba3.setText("Tabla: " + tableId  + "\n" + "moreRecords: " + moreRecords + "\n" +"records: " + records );





                }
            }else {
                prueba3.setText("code: " + response.code() + " Conexión fallida " + "\n");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR " + statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoginUser> call, Throwable t) {
            prueba3.setText("problema: " +t.getMessage());

        }
    });
```

Mi XML

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/conexionActivity"
    android:layout_width="162dp"
    android:layout_height="37dp"
    android:hint="Estado de la conexión"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.508"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.034" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Usuario"
    android:layout_width="259dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Usuario"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.19"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.185" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Password"
    android:layout_width="266dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="contraseña"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.278" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="236dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="Prueba"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.64"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="236dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
    android:onClick="Logearse"
    android:text="Ingresar"
    app:backgroundTint="@null"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.105"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/prueba3"
    android:layout_width="348dp"
    android:layout_height="101dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:text="prueba"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/prueba"
    android:layout_width="322dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="124dp"
    android:text="prueba"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.715"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/prueba4"
    android:layout_width="187dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.316"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" /
```

Estoy usando la libreria Retrofit y usando metodo POST para poder recuperarlo,

```
public interface Conexion {
@POST("jderest/v3/orchestrator/MQ0302A_ORCH")
Call <LoginUser> getUser(@Body Cuerpo users );
```

**Finalmente mi consulta es, Cómo puedo poner todo el rowset en un textView, RecyclewView o lo que me recomienden, otra cosa a aclarar es que en algun momento voy a tener que acceder a alguno de los objetos para modificarlos.
desde ya muchas gracias!**